# Ionic Beta: How to define ion-tabs with separate component?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Angular JS (7.1.4) with the beta Ionic framework (5.0.0-beta.21).

I have two tabs: Home and History in the UI. From the [documentation of ionic tabs](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs/#router-integration), I have added RechargeComponent and RechargeHistoryComponent respectively.

```
    //in the home.component.html

<ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab component="RechargeComponent" tab="home"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab component="RechargeHistoryComponent" tab="history"></ion-tab>

        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
            <ion-tab-button tab="home">
                <ion-label>Home</ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="home"></ion-icon>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button tab="history">
                <ion-label>History</ion-label>
                <ion-icon name="bookmarks"></ion-icon>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
```

I have imported both components in home.component.ts.

```
import { RechargeComponent } from "../recharge/recharge.component";
import { RechargeHistoryComponent } from "../recharge-history/recharge-history.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  entryComponents: [
    RechargeComponent, RechargeHistoryComponent
  ]
})
```

I have declared it in the app.module.ts as well.

```
import { RechargeHistoryComponent } from './recharge-history/recharge-history.component';
import { RechargeComponent } from './recharge/recharge.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RechargeHistoryComponent,
    RechargeComponent
```

[image: UI]

In the console, it gives the error of

> core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for RechargeComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>   Error: No component factory found for RechargeComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
>       at noComponentFactoryError

Comment: Try adding the entryComponents to the app.module.ts

Comment: @Adrian Yes. I have added it in the entryComponents and it still prompts the same error.